# jQuery Event Delegation for certain links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble delegating a click function to only certain links. Essentially, I'm trying to trigger a simple fadeout for all internal links that won't kill a lightbox functionality. Here's my problem (in essence):

HTML

```
<body>
   <a href="lightbox-images"></a>
   <div id="fade">
      <p>some content</p>
      <a href="example.com"></a>
      <a href="example2.com"></a>
   </div>
</body>
```

jQuery

```
$("#fade").on("click", "a", function () {

// get the href attribute
var newUrl = $(this).attr("href");

// veryfy if the new url exists or is a hash
if (!newUrl || newUrl[0] === "#") {
    // set that hash
    location.hash = newUrl;
    return;
}

// now, fadeout the html (whole page)
$("body").fadeOut(function () {
    // when the animation is complete, set the new location
    location = newUrl;
});

// prevent the default browser behavior.
return false;
});
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. The function isn't executed on any links. I'm trying to delegate it to all links within the wrapper id of "fade."

When I change

```
$("#fade").on("click", "a", function () {
```

to

```
$("document").on("click", "a", function () {
//specifying all links
```

The fade works perfectly, but it destroys the lightbox function that is needed for the site.

Is there a better way to delegate links for this event? Or perhaps not include the lightbox links in a different manner? Ideally I would keep the code above for executing on all links using `$("document")` and exclude the lightbox gallery from the function, but I don't know how I could do that.

Comment: Are you certain that element `#fade` is present in the DOM when you are binding this handler?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `$("document").on("click", "#fade a", function () {`

Comment: @AntonioManete That worked! Thank you! I can't believe I hadn't tried that, I'm a noob with javascript... still a bit confused as to why my method wasn't working but thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AntonioManente's workaround implies `#fade` is *not* present in the DOM at the time you are binding. The reason it works is by design by jQuery, however your original approach - had you got it working - is in general more specific and optimal performance-wise.